# Change Application Windows by scrolling in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, scrolling

I was using Ubuntu 18.04, in which I was able to **switch between application windows** by scrolling on the app icons in the side pane.

[image]

But when I reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 this feature is not available.

### How to enable scroll to switch applications windows

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This setting is not exposed to the user in Ubuntu 18.04 and up, but you can enable this behaviour with the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock scroll-action 'cycle-windows'
```

To reset to the default behaviour (i.e., `do-nothing`), execute the command:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock scroll-action
```

Comment: Thanks brother, it helped.

Comment: The second command must be `reset` instead of `set`, right? Apart from that, does this require the extension “Dash to dock” to be installed, or is that extension only a GUI? For me, `gnome-extensions list` doesn’t report it as installed, but it still seems to work.

Comment: @caw many thanks, corrected! Ubuntu Dock is actually a fork of Dash to Dock and uses the same dconf settings. That is why these are there even if Dash to Dock is not installed.